# Writing an accurate SDP solver in Matlab

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, numerical-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

As part of a research project I'm supposed to write an semidefinite programming solver in Matlab (similar to SDTP3, MOSEK, SEDUM, etc) except it needs to be able to solve to many significant digits accurately, where many of these solvers may only have ~3 or 4 significant digits.

I have essentially no experience with SDP/LMI's, and was wondering what the best way to go about learning a bit about this would be, and if anyone has any ideas for what might be the best algorithms and methods to use to build this? I'm at a bit of a loss after looking into it for a while and would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you so much for all your time!

Comment: You are likely aware, but if not, the definitive text on convex optimization is Boyd and Vandenberghe. At the very least the text discusses formulations and the interior point methods typically used to solve SDPs. The pdf is available at:

https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

As for accuracy issues, I imagine you will have to take care when handling the Hessian matrices (factoring, manipulating, etc.), but I'm not too sure.

Comment: Why do you say that many of those solvers only may have 3-4 digits of precision? I don't think it's true. Mosek for example should solve to something like machine precision. These solvers use interior point methods, and one of the features of interior point methods is that they attain high accuracy.

Comment: Hmm. I don't agree with the "3-4" digits number, bit I don't agree with @littleO's "machine precision" claim, either. In practice the goal tends to be around `sqrt(eps)`, or 8 digits. Which is plenty in most applications, but not all; and even that goal is not always achieved. There is plenty of academic interest in solvers that do better; google "arbitrary precision" "sdp" and you'll get some hits.

Comment: That said: it's frankly a bit surprising that someone with "essentially no experience with SDPs/LMIs" would be expected to implement a high-precision semidefinite solver. That seems quite premature. How about just implementing one in double-precision first?

Comment: [SDPA-GMP](http://sdpa.sourceforge.net/download.html) is a highly accurate multiple-precision arithmetic solver. There is also an exact arithmetic solver called [SPECTRA](http://homepages.laas.fr/henrion/software/spectra/).